# Excel formula - creating number pattern with increments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Parent

```
5000000
50000001B00
50000002B00
50000003B00
50000004B00
50000005B00
5000001
50000011B00
50000012B00
50000013B00
50000014B00
50000015B00
5000002
50000021B00
50000022B00
50000023B00
50000024B00
50000025B00
5000003
50000031B00
50000032B00
50000033B00
50000034B00
50000035B00
```

This is the pattern i am trying to achieve. Does anyone have any suggestions on a formula. I currently use several formulas that create sequential numbering patterns but haven't needed to create this type of pattern before.

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. SU is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [How to Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to achieve with 2 columns and the & operator.

[image]

You can then hide the C column.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for clearly explaining the problem.

This formula will do it:

```
=IF(MOD(ROW()-1,6)=0,"500000"&TRUNC(ROW()-1,6)/6,"500000"&INT((ROW()-1)/6)&MOD(ROW()-1,6)&"B00")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also try the following formula without the need of helper columns. Enter this at any cell and copy down in the column:

```
=5000000+INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/6) & REPT(MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,6)&"B00", MOD(ROW(1:1),6)<>1)
```

Comment: Another slick one.  Very nice.